# Order posts by posts_id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have on the template this function

```
function wp_posts( $layout = 'blog-posts' ) {

    if ( have_posts() ) :
        $i = 1;
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        do_action('fwp_before_post_content');
            get_template_part('extend-helpers/' . $layout);
        do_action('fwp_after_post_content');
        $i++;
        endwhile;
        else:
            get_template_part('extend-helpers/content', 'none');
        endif;

    }
```

What can I do to sort the posts by the IDs I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function wp_posts( $layout = 'blog-posts' ) {

    global $query_string;
    query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=id&order=ASC');

    if ( have_posts() ) :
        $i = 1;
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        do_action('fwp_before_post_content');
            get_template_part('extend-helpers/' . $layout);
        do_action('fwp_after_post_content');
        $i++;
        endwhile;
    else:
        get_template_part('extend-helpers/content', 'none');
    endif;

}
?>
```

Comment: Idea it's to sort by exact id...maybe to use an array? or how can I do?

Comment: All post should be sorted with this function.

Comment: Nvm. A case of you: query_posts($query_string . '&p=1,2,3'); Where 1,2,3 - IDs

Comment: The 'p' parameter takes a single post ID, as an integer. :(

Answer (score 0):

below code will show custom post type "testimonial" orderby ID in descending order

```
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query= null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('post_type=testimonial&post_status=publish&showposts=4&orderby=ID&order=DESC' . '&paged='.$paged);
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : 
    $wp_query->the_post(); 
  endwhile;
```